# CakePHP does not read the correct input names in a cloned form generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cakephp

I've implemented an extend form function that also generates unique field names as a form is cloned.

Because of how the js works, the field names in the extend form base (#readroot) are not Cake-compatible until the script is run and corrects them.

Names in base: **age, grade, school**
What it looks like after js is run:

`data[Student][1][age]`

`data[Student][1][grade]`

`data[Student][1][school]`

So I expect `$this->request->data` would receive an array like this:

```
Array ( 
[Post] => Array ( 
    [title] => Mr 
    [contact_person] => Sam 
    [home_tel] => 1234567 
    [mobile] => 1234567 
    [email] => email@gmail.com 
    [relationship] => family 
    [frequency] => once per week 
    [duration] => 1hr 
    [user_id] => 1 
) 
[Student] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [age] => 10
        [grade] => 1 
        [gender] => 1
        [school] => ABC
    ) 
    // This is where the extend form starts.
    [1] => Array (
        [age] => 11
        [grade] => 2
        [gender] => 0
        [school] => ABC2
    )
)
)
```

However, `$this->request->data` reads this:

```
Array ( 
[age] => 11
[grade] => 2 
[gender] => 0
[school] => ABC2 
[Post] => Array ( 
    [title] => Mr 
    [contact_person] => Sam
    [home_tel] => 1234567 
    [mobile] => 1234567 
    [email] => email@gmail.com 
    [relationship] => family 
    [frequency] => once per week
    [duration] => 1hr 
    [user_id] => 1 
) 
[Student] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [age] => 10 
        [grade] => 1 
        [gender] => 1
        [school] => ABC 
    ) 
) )
```

It appears it reads the field names prior to the change. I'm new to Javascript and hopefully someone can save me...

The simplified version of the form html and javascript:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('contact_person');
echo $this->Form->input('home_tel');
echo $this->Form->input('mobile');
echo $this->Form->input('email'); 
echo $this->Form->input('relationship'); 
echo $this->Form->input('Student.0.age');       
echo $this->Form->input('Student.0.grade');         
echo $this->Form->input('Student.0.school'); 
?>
<!-- Extend Form Reference -->
<span id="readroot" style="display: none">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />
    <?php 
    echo $this->Form->input('Student.1.age', array(
        'name' => 'age',
    ); 
    echo $this->Form->input('Student.1.grade', array(
        'name' => 'grade',
        'options' => array(
            '1' => __('Grade 1'),   
            '2' => __('Grade 2')
        )
    )); 
    echo $this->Form->input('Student.1.school', array(
        'name' => 'school'
    )); 
    ?>
</span>
<!-- Extend Form Reference End-->
<span id="writeroot"></span>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!" />
<script>
    var counter = 1;
    function moreFields() {
        counter++;
        var newField = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
        newField.id = '';
        newField.style.display = 'block';
        var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name]');
            for (var i=0;i<newFields.length;i++) {
                var theNames = newFields[i].name
                if (theNames)
                    newFields[i].name = "data[Student][" + counter + "][" + theNames + "]";

        }
        var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField,insertHere);
    }
    //window.onload = moreFields;
</script>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I managed to make it work, not in a elegant way though, I post it as an answer.

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Post->create();
        $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = AuthComponent::user('id');
        unset($this->Post->Student->validate['post_id']);
        $a = $this->request->data;
        $b = array_splice($a, 4);
        if ($this->Post->saveAssociated($b)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post has been saved.'), 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-danger'));
        }
    }
    $users = $this->Post->User->find('list', array('order' => array('User.id' => 'asc')));
    $subjects = $this->Post->Subject->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users', 'subjects'));
    }
```

There are 4 values up front whereas the rest of the array is exactly how I wanted, I basically just cut it off and pass the rest to save..

Answer (score 0):

Well because you override the data attribute with something else other than `Student.1.grade` (in your case, `grade`).

That's why Cake form helper is adding it to the root of the array instead of the School key.

Your code should look like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Student.1.grade', array(
    'name' => 'Student.1.grade',
    'options' => array(
        '1' => __('Grade 1'),   
        '2' => __('Grade 2')
    )
));
```

OR

```
echo $this->Form->input('Student.1.grade', array(
    'options' => array(
        '1' => __('Grade 1'),   
        '2' => __('Grade 2')
    )
));
```

Comment: I am doing this on purpose because the script requires a base name in the base form to dynamically generate field names as the form is cloned. If I click 'Give me more fields!' the cloned form will have field names like 'data[Student][1][grade]' which increments as more forms are cloned